# VS2017 xamarin project rebuild freezes

Tags: xamarin-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have installed VS2017 and have a simple xamarin project in VS2017.
When rebuilding the solution, vs2017 appears to hang.

Restarting VS2017 does not fix the issue. Rebooting the PC does fix it but then after a few builds it will freeze again.

(the code essentially remains consistent - just whitespace changes to try and mitigate code issues)

I have tried leaving the build running for several minutes and even several hours, but once it fails to build it never will, until I reboot the PC.

It does though allow me to cancel the build upon which it dumps a detailed log. (i have changed the build output settings to "detailed").

It does not matter how long I leave the build but when I cancel it, the build output always appears to "freeze" at the same point.

Below are the last few lines of the build output:

```
1>Done executing task "CreateProperty".
1>Done building target "_ResolveMonoAndroidSdks" in project "Insync2.csproj".
1>Target "_SetupDesignTimeBuildForIntellisense" in file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets" from project "C:\Users\baldevsandhu\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Insync2\Insync2\Insync2.csproj" (target "_GetPrimaryCpuAbi" depends on it):
1>Done building target "_SetupDesignTimeBuildForIntellisense" in project "Insync2.csproj".
1>Target "_GetPrimaryCpuAbi" in file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets" from project "C:\Users\baldevsandhu\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Insync2\Insync2\Insync2.csproj" (target "_CheckInstantRunCondition" depends on it):
1>Using "GetPrimaryCpuAbi" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Build.Debugging.Tasks.dll".
1>Task "GetPrimaryCpuAbi"
1>  Adb Task:
1>    AdbTarget: 
1>    AdbOptions: 
1>    DevicePropertyCache: obj\Debug\devices.cache
1>  Reading properties for emulator-5554
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(308,2): warning : One or more errors occurred.
1>Done executing task "GetPrimaryCpuAbi".
1>Done building target "_GetPrimaryCpuAbi" in project "Insync2.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:10:05.74
Build has been canceled.
```

Has anyone seen this issue before?

I did have VS2015 installed first, but this has since been uninstalled.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue.  There are a couple of possible solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112230/visual-studio-regularly-freezes-running-microsoft-visualstudio-web-host-exe), but i've not tried anything yet...

Comment: I have this issue too :| in enterprise version! I ran the VS by `Run As Administrator` but nothing had change.