# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe taking over

Tags: visual-studio, iis

My solution consists of a 195 (not a typo) C# MVC application projects w/ some ASPX pages as well running on VS2017 on Windows 10.  Its nothing bleeding edge.  A days ago, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe" started taking over my machine.

Here is what I have experienced.

The app (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe) will keep VS2017 from loading a solution I'm trying to open.
The only fix is to kill the offending exe via Task Manager.

The app will keep VS2017 from exiting when a solution I'm using is open.
The only fix is to kill the offending exe via Task Manager.

When trying to build, things slow to a grind.
The only fix is to kill the offending exe via Task Manager.

**The offending app will use as many resources as possible.**

I've done Win10 an Symantec virus scans on the offender.  Both scans came back negative.

I've tried adjusting the app's settings in task manager so that only one or two cores can be used by the process.  This helps, but sometimes I still have to kill the app to get things working in VS2017.

Whenever I kill the app, it comes back within 30 seconds.

Sometimes, things work fine.  No discernible reason why.

iisreset does nothing.

I resorted to renaming the EXE file, that way it couldn't attack me again.

That seems to work, but its a hack.

Does anyone know what the root cause is, and how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried some of this solutions and tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112230/visual-studio-regularly-freezes-running-microsoft-visualstudio-web-host-exe

Comment: @SehaxX Nothing on that page worked, and some of the 'solutions' were poorly explained and I couldn't follow them.

Comment: What happens if you run without any active virus scanners (incl. Windows Defender)?

Comment: @pfx The offending app still tries to take over.  Good question.

Comment: Sorry for simular question; you have no anti-malware or alike software running with some kind of realtime protection shield? Had lots of troubles with such one.
Other question, did you try monitoring what that process is doing via eg. Sysinternals Process Monitor?

Comment: What happens if you do the following [disable intellitrace and diagnostic tools](http://accentient.com/blog/vs2015-diagnostics-tools-window/) and [disable full solution analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt709421.aspx)?